# restrict subscribers to admin area. They have their own profile on fron-end

Tags: plugins

I want to make a simple website where users can register to my site. they can have their profile page. when they login they should be redirected to their profile page. Subscribers should not be allowed to view their profile in admin side.

suggest me plugins or way to do it.

Thanking for answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need any plugin.just add this code to your function.php file which you will find in your theme folder.

```
add_action( 'init', 'blockusers_init' );

function blockusers_init() {
    if ( is_admin() && current_user_can( 'subscriber' ) ) {
        wp_redirect( home_url() );
        exit;
    }
}
```